# Delete all data from specific Realm Object Swift

Tags: swift, persistence, realm

Before i get too far into my question. My goal, which may influence your answers, is to remove `Object` data if it is no longer in the cloud.

So if I have an array `["one", "two", "three"]`

Then in my server I remove `"two"`

I want my realm to update the change.

I figure the best way to do this is to delete all data in the specific `Object`, then call my REST API to download the new data. If there is a better way, please let me know.

Okay so here is my problem.

I have an Object `Notifications()`

every time my REST API is called, before it downloads anything I am running this:

```
let realm = Realm()
let notifications = Notifications()
realm.beginWrite()
realm.delete(notifications)
realm.commitWrite()
```

I get this error after running: `Can only delete an object from the Realm it belongs to.`

so i tried something like this:

```
for notification in notifications {
    realm.delete(notification)
}
realm.commitWrite()
```

The error I get within xcode is this: `"Type Notifications does not conform to protocol 'SequenceType'`

Not really sure where to go from here.

Just trying to figure out realm. Completely new to it

Note: `realm.deleteAll()` works, but I don't want all of my realm deleted, just certain `Objects`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You're looking for this:

```
let realm = Realm()
let deletedValue = "two"
realm.write {
  let deletedNotifications = realm.objects(Notifications).filter("value == %@", deletedValue)
  realm.delete(deletedNotifications)
}
```

or perhaps this:

```
let realm = Realm()
let serverValues = ["one", "three"]
realm.write {
  realm.delete(realm.objects(Notifications)) // deletes all 'Notifications' objects from the realm
  for value in serverValues {
    let notification = Notifications()
    notification.value = value
    realm.add(notification)
  }
}
```

Although ideally, you'd be setting a primary key on `Notifications` so that you can simply update those existing objects rather than taking the extreme approach of nuking all your local objects simply to recreate them all (or almost).